# Getting more than 1 post from a sub at a time

Tags: discord, discord.py, praw

```
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='xyz',
                     client_secret='xyz',
                     user_agent='xyz',check_for_async=False)
@bot.command(aliases=['memes'])
async def meme(ctx):
    memes_submissions = reddit.subreddit('dankmemes').new()
    post_to_pick = random.randint(1, 10)
    for i in range(0, post_to_pick):
        submission = next(x for x in memes_submissions if not x.stickied)
    embed = discord.Embed(title= f"Meme-" ,color=0xFF00FF)
    embed.set_image(url=submission.url)
    '''embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)'''
    embed.set_footer(text='requested by: \n{0}'.format(ctx.author),icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

i wrote this down to extract 1 meme at a time from reddit sub "*dankmemes*"
i was wondering if theres a way through which i can ask for top 5 memes or get more than just one meme?

any suggestions will be of a lot of help. tysm!

Comment: I don't think you should use praw as its kind of dying and very slow. You can try [RedditEasy](https://github.com/MakufonSkifto/RedditEasy). It's made by me and its 2x faster than praw! And an answer to your question: I don't think there is a way to get 2 posts at 1 time.

Comment: @EmirSürmen WOW ill give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can get top posts from a subreddit by using the subreddit.top member.

```
max_top = 5
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('sample_subreddit_with_good_memes')
top = subreddit.top(limit=max_top)
```

The built-in random library has a function named choices() which gives you a list with multiple randomly selected choices. So you can basically get the top 100 posts and then get 10 random memes from the list.